# How to pass objects in UriTemplates in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

The below code was used to expose RESTful application using WCF. Here I pass the input through `UriTemplate` objects, which are used in the `AddDetailsRequest` class.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyRestService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "AddEmployee")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "AddEmpDetails/{objReq}")]
    AddDetailsResponse AddEmpDetails(AddDetailsRequest objReq);
}
```

Class `AddDetailsRequest`

```
[DataContract(Name = "AddDetailsRequest")]
public class AddDetailsRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

What the problem I was faced here means, I am not able to pass the objects through `UriTemplate`. I want to pass the object, which has 2 parameters (Name and City), in a `UriTemplate`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF UriTemplate does not support complex objects. In this case you have to stick with primary types from .NET. If you still want to use a complex object as parameter to your method you have to drop the UriTemplate and pass your object using JSON. If you really don't want to drop the UriTemplate your last option is to use a string parameter:

```
AddDetailsResponse AddEmpDetails(string objEncodedReq);
```

Where `objEncodedReq` is your serialized object (XML serialized fro example) and encoded using Base64. You would have to do this from client level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a newbie to WCF, can u keep me to achieve this by using JSON as you said. If you give some sample links about this type, would be greatful for me. I am expecting your reply soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link of which content should help you create a WCF REST JSON service in no time: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec

Comment: Hi, above link was not used with complex objects. it was just a basic WCF using JSON. Please give some other links which has Complex objects using JSON. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON and http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/passing-json-serialized-objects-wcf-service-jquery/

Comment: I have a little doubt in the above post you gave primordialcode.com/blog/post/. As it explained about how to pass the JSON objects to WCF service was good and clear. "var msg2 = { "msg": { "Id": "2", "Sender": "Webpage", "Text": "Sended Text"} };" The above is the input object(name = msg) that is passed to the JQuery script, This object was hard coded by default in head section of the Javascript. Now my question is How to pass this object to WCF service? Bcoz i am creating a WCF service & it is going to be used by Client, While using it, by which way he will pass the inputs? Thanks in advance.